# model not mapped in hibernate for date sql query

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I need to display a value with respect to date column by only passing the month value as 01 for Jan and 02 for Feb like so. i tried with the hibernate query but  its shows an error.

```
@Query("select to_char(calendarDate,'mm'),dayType from Calendar 
where calendarDate like '%?1%'")
List<String>findDayType(int callist);
```

I'm getting

> model not mapped in hibernate

error for this above query

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of using DATE as a type is so the database can efficiently query the data. It's the same reason you store a number as an INT and not a VARCHAR - so the engine can make intelligent decisions. If you use the LIKE operator on a date, you lose the benefits of having chosen the correct data type.

Using MONTH allows SQL to grab the month portion of the  column that it knows adheres to the DATE data format. When you use LIKE, it's doing character-by-character pattern matching which is significantly costlier and slower to do.

If LIKE was sufficient, then MONTH() wouldn't exist. Any built in function is always going to be the choice over LIKE for a DATE query.

Comment: thank you for your reply. can i get a sample query to retrieve the month using 01 as jan,02 as feb

Comment: Mark as answer if its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Current month**

```
SELECT DATENAME(mm, GETDATE()) 'English Month Name'
```

**For another months**

```
DECLARE @Mth smallint
SET @Mth = 11
SELECT DateName(mm,DATEADD(mm,@Mth,-1)) as [MonthName]
```

Comment: In second case it returns 'November'

Answer (score 0):

This is the proper query and now it's working:

```
@Query("select to_char(calendarDate,'mm'),dayType from Calendar where calendarDate =?1")
List<String>findDayType(int callist);
```